# VBA code to replace table with filters with the data that is filtered

Tags: excel, vba

Exist any good&effective way with VBA to change a table with many filters applied to remove all the rest of data which is irrelevant (not being filtered)? The goal is to remove from the xlsm the data not needed. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want??

```
Sub DropHidden()
   Dim EquivRange As Range, r As Range
   Dim lo As ListObject
   Dim nFirstRow As Long, nLastRow As Long
   Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)

   With lo
      Set EquivRange = .DataBodyRange
      nFirstRow = EquivRange.Row
      nLastRow = EquivRange.Rows.Count + EquivRange.Row - 1
      For i = nLastRow To nFirstRow Step -1
         Set r = Cells(i, 1).EntireRow
         If r.Hidden Then
            r.Delete
         End If
      Next i
      .Unlist
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As sometimes although questions mentioned tables but in fact the reference relates to ranges of data and also it's not clear as to whether the requirement is to delete entire rows or just the filtered part of the row. I'm providing four procedures tall will work for the following situations:

1. Excel Tables - Delete Non-Filtered Items - Entire Row

   ```
   Sub Lob_Delete_NonFilteredItems_EntireRow()
   Dim Lob As ListObject, rRow As Range
       'Set Lob = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(TblName)      'Set Table Name as required
       Set Lob = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)            'Set Table Index as required
       For Each rRow In Lob.DataBodyRange.Rows
           If rRow.EntireRow.Hidden Then rRow.EntireRow.Delete
       Next
   End Sub
   ```
2. Excel Tables - Delete Non-Filtered Items - Row Shift Up

   ```
   Sub Lob_Delete_NonFilteredItems_RowShiftUp()
   Dim Lob As ListObject, rVsble As Range, rRow As Range, rDel As Range
       Rem Set List Object - Excel Table
       'Set Lob = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(TblName)      'Set Table Name as required
       Set Lob = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)            'Set Table Index as required
       Rem Set Filtered Range
       Set rVsble = Lob.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
       Rem Set Filters Off
       rVsble.Cells(1).Activate
       On Error Resume Next
       ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
       On Error GoTo 0
       Rem Set Range To be Deleted
       For Each rRow In Lob.DataBodyRange.Rows
           If Application.Intersect(rRow, rVsble) Is Nothing Then
               If rDel Is Nothing Then
                   Set rDel = rRow
               Else
                   Set rDel = Union(rDel, rRow)
       End If: End If: Next
       Rem Delete Rows
       rDel.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End Sub
   ```
3. Excel Range - Delete Non-Filtered Items - Entire Row

   ```
   Sub Rng_Delete_NonFilteredItems_EntireRow()
   Dim rBdy As Range, rRow As Range
       Rem Validate Worksheet AutoFilter
       If ActiveSheet.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
       Rem Set AutoFilter Range
       With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
           Set rBdy = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(-1 + .Rows.Count)
       End With
       For Each rRow In rBdy.Rows
           If rRow.EntireRow.Hidden Then
               rRow.EntireRow.Delete
          End If
       Next
   End Sub
   ```
4. Excel Range - Delete Non-Filtered Items - Row Shift Up

   ```
   Sub Rng_Delete_NonFilteredItems_RowShiftUp()
   Dim rBdy As Range, rVsble As Range, rRow As Range, rDel As Range
       Rem Validate Worksheet AutoFilter
       If ActiveSheet.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
       Rem Set AutoFilter Range
       With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
           Set rBdy = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(-1 + .Rows.Count)
       End With
       Rem Set Filtered Range
       Set rVsble = rBdy.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
       Rem Set Filters Off
       On Error Resume Next
       ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
       On Error GoTo 0
       Rem Set Range To be Deleted
       For Each rRow In rBdy.Rows
           If Application.Intersect(rRow, rVsble) Is Nothing Then
               If rDel Is Nothing Then
                   Set rDel = rRow
               Else
                   Set rDel = Union(rDel, rRow)
       End If: End If: Next
       Rem Delete Rows
       rDel.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End Sub
   ```